# SpringBoot 3: DataSource issue with SpringBatch 5

Tags: spring-batch

As part of the migration to Spring Batch 5.0, the documentation says `javax.*` classes have been replaced with `jakarta.*`. However, Spring Batch API still references `javax.`.

Here is an example with `JdbcCursorItemReader`.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

   @Autowired
   private jakarta.activation.DataSource dataSource;

   @Bean
   public ItemReader<T> reader() {
      JdbcCursorItemReader<T> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
      // Requires javax's datasource and not Jarkata.
      reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
   } 

}
```

I don't currently see a path forward for me right now in reading to or from a database in Spring Batch 5 unless there is some documentation I can reference. I don't see it in the [what's new](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html) or [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide).

Comment: What is the error when you use `javax.sql.DataSource`?

Comment: I don’t understand the problem. Are you asking how to create a data source using jakarta libs? If your question is “how do I connect to the database using Jakarta libs”, that’s got little to do with Spring. Also, Jakarta is mostly rebranding and the underlying code is very similar

Comment: No, not creating a datasource. This is specific to spring batch.  If you look at the example I put in the code snipet, JdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(DataSource) expects a javax.sql.DataSource and not a jakarta.activation.DataSource. It will give you a compile-time error.

Comment: [JdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractCursorItemReader.html#setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)) indeed expects a `javax.sql.DataSource`. Now that is established, what is the problem in giving it so?

Comment: Per my earlier response above, a compile-time error is thrown. If you are asking why not continue using java.sql.DataSource, the documentation says clearly to no longer reference javax.

Comment: The answer by Michael is correct. I just want to add that the documentation clearly says to change `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` for **EE APIs**. Here is an excerpt from the wiki: `Jakarta EE 9: Please make sure to update your import statements from javax.* to jakarta.* for all EE APIs you use`. As Micheal mentioned, `javax.sql.*` is part of Java SE and you have nothing to migrate for that part, so you should be able to use `javax.sql.DataSource` with Spring Batch 5 and Spring Boot 3.

Comment: It is funny how someone can say this does not show any research effort when I already provided references to the effect and I am providing feedback. Whoever did this is doing this in bad faith. I can also say that some of the questions being asked here shows that some commenting here do not even know what they are commenting about.

Comment: This platform used to be better than this. Please do better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`javax.sql.*` is a JDK package and not part of Java EE. The latter lived indeed under the `javax.*` package and it has been taken over by the Eclipse foundation. Those APIs will evolve under `jakarta.*` packages. Javax as a name is trademarked and not donated to the community.

In short: you don’t todo anything here.

For reference, see the JDK Javadoc of `DataSource`

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html

`javax.activation.DataSource` respectively `jakarta.activation.DataSource` are different APIs and neither are used by the JDBC item reader.

Comment: I guess I did not clarify my main issue. I don't currently see a path forward for me right now in reading to or from a database in Spring Batch 5 unless there is a documentation I can reference. I can't see it in the migration guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked. I suppose due to the phrasing of the question, it was hard to understand. I've edited it to make the problem clearer.

Comment: It is the correct answer. The jakarta.activation.DataSource has nothing todo with the class of the same name in javax.sql.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The documentation clearly says to change `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` **for EE APIs**, not for SE APIs. Here is an excerpt from the wiki: `Jakarta EE 9: Please make sure to update your import statements from javax.* to jakarta.* for all EE APIs you use.`. As Micheal mentioned, `javax.sql.*` is part of Java SE and you have nothing to migrate for that part, so you should be able to use `javax.sql.DataSource` with Spring Batch 5 and Spring Boot 3.